# CSS - how to in-line form/input but stack each line with the proper indent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, flexbox

[image]

This is currently my layout, and I'm having a tough time aligning and properly centering these at the same time

**Desired output:**

```
 Username: [Input]

 Password: [Input]
```

But would also like username,password to be right indented and the input to line up with each other as well.

I know there's tutorials out there but can seem to have it work on my code specifically.Please see code below

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Billabong';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('/instagram-clone/fonts/Billabong.woff') format('woff');
    }

body {
    display: block; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:0px; 
    margin:0px;
    height: auto;
}

.titlecontainer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:0px; 
    width:400px;
    height:40px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Billabong;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(176deg, rgba(43,104,140,1) 0%, rgba(28,97,138,1) 100%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
   
}


.inputcontainer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    margin: -2px auto;
    border-radius: 4px; 
}

.login {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <div class="titlecontainer">
      <h2 id = "igtitle">Instagram</h2>
  </div>

<div class="inputcontainer">
  
  <div class="login">
    <label for="password">Username:<label>
    <input id = "pwinput" type = "text" name="password"/>
   <label for="password">Password:<label>
    <input id = "pwinput" type = "text" name="password"/>
   
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't wrap each label/input pair in a div?

Comment: Okay that's a start - how do I begin formatting the indents? This is where I'm stuck

Comment: What I normally do for this kind of layout is make the labels display: inline-block, then set the same width on both. You can do more complex things with CSS grids but it's overkill for this use case.

Comment: I added a very simple answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.login label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <div>
    <label for="password">Username:</label>
    <input id = "pwinput" type = "text" name="password"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id = "pwinput" type = "text" name="password"/>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks - so when I past that code you have above. The Username, UserInput and Password, PWInput are on separate blocks

Comment: If you click "run code snippet" you'll see it's working as expected, so I imagine something in the page or page style is affecting it.